Canonization of Tanakh
Given that the Talmud records disputes among great chachamim about the status of certain books of Ketuvim, how can we be fully confident that these books are in fact authoritative and true?

One interesting possible approach for answering is suggested by R’ Lebens in ch 7 of Principles of Judaism.

The whole dispute is merely with regards to the sanctity of the physical parchment upon which the books are written, but everyone agrees that all of the books are authoritative and true, e.g. everyone holds of the holiday of Purim, even though some hold that the book of Esther has no sanctity (Megillah 7a)

You could say that "the Torah is not in heaven" and if the sages decided on this set, that's good enough. Could they have added a different one or taken one away? Maybe, but that's not what was decided.

How is this different from any other dispute?

There's nothing empirically "fully confident and true" in Judaism. The 24 books of Tanach are considered authoritative and true de-jure and posteriorly.

The people deciding the canonization seemed to have been the Anshei knesset hagdolah (see Avot d'Ribbi Natan 1:4), included in them were the last of the prophets (Avot d'Ribbi Natan 1:3). Being prophets, they knew had some form of confirmation from Hashem on what they were saying and what they decided (like when they tried to say Shlomo has no portion in the world to come Bamidbar Rabbah 14:1). Being the last of the prophets, they closed off the text of Tanach (no Maccabees or New Testament) and may have rejected certain previous books such as Wars of Hashem, Divrei Hayamim of the Kings of Israel, Ben Sira (see Seder HaDorot), Sefer Hanoch, and I assume there are more.
The Tumah status of certain books were discussed later (Yadayim 3:5) but not in regards to them being authorative or not.

Where in your first citation does it support your initial claim?

בראשונה היו אומרים משלי ושיר השירים וקהלת גנוזים היו שהם היו אומרים משלות ואינן מן הכתובים ועמדו וגנזו אותם עד שבאו אנשי כנסת הגדולה ופירשו אותם
this shows they decided to include it. I changed to see instead of direct quote

All that says is they helped rescue the three "solomon wisdom" books, not the wider claim "The people deciding the canonization seemed to have been the Anshei knesset hagdolah"

"אינן מן הכתובים... עד שבאו אנשי כנסת הגדולה" מכלל לאו אתה שומע הין

There's no lav or hein to hear. I don't have a clue what you're talking about

Anyway nothing here even answers the question. Even if the AKG decided on the canon, there were apparently still later disputes and the OPs question follows.

where and what is disputed? the mishna in yadayim clearly has ribbi akiva saying shir hashirim is holy yet not tamei. therefore one cannot use dispute of tumah status as a dispute about their canonization. I assumed that was the source of dispute. unfortunately OP didnt include any sources so idk of any other "later disputes"
